# VSCode - git branch opens Vim

Tags: git, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm using Git inside the VSCode terminal and it works.
However, if I run **git branch** it opens the **Vim** editor, so that I need to run **:wq** to come back to the terminal!

Is this the normal behaviour or something is wrong with my VSCode settings?

Comment: Do this: `git config --global pager.branch 'false' ` to stop vim from being opened

Answer (score 0):

What editor have you configured in git? Try running

```
git config core.editor
```

To see what you have set, for me the value is

```
code --wait -n
```

Comment: For me is: code --wait -n too